# Where is the $\frac{1}{p!}$ term used in this proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

In Guillemin and Pollack they devise a method of turning a tensor into an alternating tensor. They claim, given any $p$-tensor $T$ that:

$$\text{Alt}(T) = \frac{1}{p!}\sum_{\pi \in S_p} (-1)^{\pi} T^{\pi}$$

(Where $\pi$ is a permutation, $S_p$ is the permutation group of $p$ elements)

Produces an alternating tensor. The proof they give is as follows:

> $\text{Alt}(T)$ is alternating, for it is obvious that $(-1)^{\pi \circ \sigma} = (-1)^{\pi}(-1)^{\sigma}$. Thus:
>   $$\left[ \text{Alt}(T) \right]^\sigma = \frac{1}{p!}\sum_{\pi \in S_p} (-1)^{\pi} T^{\pi \circ \sigma} = \frac{1}{p!}(-1)^{\sigma}\sum_{\pi \in S_p} (-1)^{\pi \circ \sigma} T^{\pi \circ \sigma}$$
>   If we set $\tau = \pi \circ \sigma$, as $S_p$ is a group and $\pi$ ranges through $S_p$, $\tau$ must also range through $S_p$. So:
>   $$\left[ \text{Alt}(T) \right]^\sigma = \frac{1}{p!}(-1)^{\sigma}\sum_{\pi \in S_p} (-1)^{\tau} T^{\tau} = (-1)^{\sigma} \text{Alt}(T)$$

My question is why is the coefficient $\frac{1}{p!}$ needed? The proof doesn't seem to use this fact at all.

In other words, why can we not instead define $\text{Alt}(T)$ as:

$$ \text{Alt}(T) = \sum_{\pi \in S_p} (-1)^{\pi} T^{\pi}$$

Comment: The averaging term is not necessary here, but when one wants to look at wedge products. There are a few comments in Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* in the chapter "Algebraic Preliminaries" (I think it is chapter 3).

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: They sort of mention how there is some ambiguity on the definition, but it seems silly that they don't mention this directly in the book. I'll be sure to have a look at Calculus on Manifolds when I get the chance. Thanks.

Comment: See also here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54343/is-there-a-preferable-convention-for-defining-the-wedge-product

Comment: For future reference, I'm thinking about page 79 and forward. It is chapter 4, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Lamark has pointed out, [this thread discusses issues with the definition of $Alt$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54343/is-there-a-preferable-convention-for-defining-the-wedge-product). As pointed by Pedro Tamaroff there is no need for the $\frac{1}{p!}$ term.

One remark: a nice consequence of using $\frac{1}{p!}$ that, if $T$ is alternating:

$$Alt(T) = T$$

As there are $p!$ elements in the the $S_p$ the summation reduces to:

$$p!T$$

Thus multiplying by $\frac{1}{p!}$ gives:

$$\frac{1}{p!}p!T = T$$